# Are these data enough to solve this simulataneity problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

observers: **S** and **S**'.
S stands **in midway** between two events (say, 2 flashes) located **20 metres apart**.
He sees two flashes occurring **simultaneously**.
**S'** notes a **20ns difference** in them.
**S'** is moving along x axis with uniform velocity
What is this velocity in S frame?

delta t equation leads to a 4th degree polynomial equation of v, so I must be wrong. Please help.

Comment: To get the direction of motion (i.e. sign of the velocity) you need to know which of the events that S' sees first. Just knowing the time difference you can work out the speed, but not the sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\Delta t = 0$, we have:

$\Delta t' = 20ns = \gamma \dfrac{v\Delta x}{c^2} = 20m \dfrac{\gamma v}{c^2}$

or

$\dfrac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = 0.3c$

So, yes, the relative *speed* can be found with the data given.  Hint:  square both sides.

Comment: Thankyou Alfred Centauri, I've been making the capital mistake of taking reciprocal of Lorentz factor and multiplying it with 'v'; Thankyou for your quick reply.